# Getting Time Limit Exceeded in Java even after using HashMap in "phone number query code"

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

> You are given a phone book that consists of people's names and their
> phone numbers. After that, you will be given some person's name as a
> query. For each query, print the phone number of that person.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line will have an integer denoting the number of entries in
> the phone book. Each entry consists of two lines: a name and the
> corresponding phone number.
>
> After these, there will be some queries. Each query will contain a
> person's name. Read the queries until end-of-file.
>
> Constraints: A person's name consists of only lower-case English
> letters and it may be in the format 'first-name last-name' or in the
> format 'first name'. Each phone number has exactly 8 digits without
> any leading zeros.
>
> Output Format
>
> For each case, print "Not found" if the person has no entry in the
> phone book. Otherwise, print the person's name and phone number. See
> sample output for the exact format.
>
> To make the problem easier, we provided a portion of the code in the
> editor. You can either complete that code or write completely on your
> own.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 3
> uncle sam
> 99912222
> tom
> 11122222
> harry
> 12299933
> uncle sam
> uncle tom
> harry
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> uncle sam=99912222
> Not found
> harry=12299933
> ```

So,I have tried the following code using HashMap:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        HashMap<String,String> dic=new HashMap<>(q);
        for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        {
            dic.put(sc.nextLine(),sc.nextLine());
        }
        
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
           
            String s=sc.nextLine();
            int f=0;
            String ans="";
             for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : dic.entrySet())
            {
                if ((e.getKey()).equals(s))
                {
                    f=1;
                    ans=e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue();
                }    
            }
            if (f==1)
            System.out.println(ans);
            else
            System.out.println("Not found");
           
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Please see the output here]

Comment: What are these test cases you’re trying to execute?

Comment: Its private test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using a HashMap you are still iterating all the entries in the map which violates the purpose of using a hash map.

Use `containsKey` to check if the map has a key and use `get` to get a value. Both these operations are `O(1)`.

```
....
String s = sc.nextLine();
if (dic.containsKey(s)) {
    System.out.println(s + "=" + s.get(s));
} else {
   System.out.println("Not found");
}
```